# I am trying to compare two strings in an if statement, but it is giving me an error. Why?

Tags: python, if-statement, matrix

```
itemsInExistence = []
#items are put into this matrix in a save function
#Ex. ['Sword Mk II', 4, 4]
gains = random.randint(1, 3)
if gains == 2:
  gained_weapon = random.choice(itemsInExistence)
  print("You gained the item", gained_weapon)
  itemMatrix.append(gained_weapon)
  for i in itemsInExistence:
    if gained_weapon == itemsInExistence[i]:
      del itemsInExistence[i]
      break
```

It keeps giving me the error:

> if gained_weapon == itemsInExistence[i]:
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

How would I go about fixing this without seriously changing how the items are set up?

Comment: `i` is the item not the index of the item

Comment: because `i` is a `str` which is the source of your error as you're iterating over the contents of `itemsInExistence`, not the ordinal index position

Comment: Try to `print(i)`.

Comment: I think you just need `itemsInExistence.remove(gained_weapon)` instead of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in the way you are **getting** value " *i* ".

When you use "***for i in items***", inside for loop, you get "*i = firstItem*", then "*i = secondItem*" and so on...

If you need to loop through list using index, use following pattern:

```
    for i in range( 0, len(myList) ):

        if gained_weapon == myList[i]:
           ...statements...
```

Revised Working Code:

```
    import random

    itemsInExistence = ['Sword Mk II', 4, 4]
    #items are put into this matrix in a save function
    #Ex. ['Sword Mk II', 4, 4]
    gains = random.randint(1, 3)

    print('gains: '+ str(gains) )

    if gains == 2:
      gained_weapon = random.choice(itemsInExistence)
      print("You gained the item:", gained_weapon)
      itemMatrix = []
      itemMatrix.append(gained_weapon)
      for i in range(0,len(itemsInExistence)):
            print('i: ' + str(i) )
            if gained_weapon == itemsInExistence[i]:
                print('items matched')
                del itemsInExistence[i]
                print(itemsInExistence)
                break
```

I am new to SO, let me know if I can make this answer better.
Don't forget to **upvote** if I was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following change:

```
for item in itemsInExistence:
    if gained_weapon == item:
        itemsInExistence.remove(item)
        break
```

(assuming that `itemsInExistence` is a list of strings) you could get the same effect from doing simply:

```
itemsInExistence.remove(gained_weapon)
```

instead of iterating over the whole list, even though you just want to remove one item ...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Python docs

> The for statement in Python differs a bit from what you may be used to in C or Pascal. Rather than always iterating over an arithmetic progression of numbers (like in Pascal), or giving the user the ability to define both the iteration step and halting condition (as C), Python’s for statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence.

Which is that when you iterate over the list `itemsInExistence` it doesn't give you the index of theat element as `i` but the element itself. So you may basically change it to `if gained_weapon == i:`. You will also get an error for `del itemsInExistence[i]`, but in that case you cant use `del i` to delete that element from the list. Instead you can use `list.remove()` method. [See the docs here.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `enumerate()` if you want the index along with the item.

```
for i in itemsInExistence:
    if gained_weapon == itemsInExistence[i]:
        del itemsInExistence[i]
        break
```

should become

```
for i, item in enumerate(itemsInExistence):
    if gained_weapon == itemsInExistence[i]:
        del itemsInExistence[i]
        break
```